# C++ & boost::threads - How to prioritize thread based on work type?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using C++ with boost on Linux.

What is the best way to prioritize a thread based on work type?
Is it possible to vary a thread priority in POSIX / pthread / Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know boost doesn't provide an API to do it (the C++11 standard certainly doesn't at least).

On Linux, you can [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice) or [`setpriority`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) each thread independently from the others. Note however that this is **not** POSIX-conformant:

> According to POSIX, the nice value is a per-process setting. However, under the current Linux/NPTL implementation of POSIX threads, the nice value is a per-thread attribute: different threads in the same process can have different nice values. Portable applications should avoid relying on the Linux behavior, which may be made standards conformant in the future.

Since Linux uses `pthreads` (and so does the Linux port of `boost`) you could also use [`pthread_setschedparam`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setschedparam) which has the advantage of being more portable than the Linux-specific per-thread `nice` behaviour.

In both cases, there's the slight uneasiness due to having to resort to system facilities in order to manage supposedly "opaque" `boost` (or `std` in C++11) resources, so tread carefully (as with anything implementation-specific).

Comment: If one of these re-niced threads forks, will the child have the priority of the thread or the original process?